# IIS doesn't work when RRAS with NAT is enabled for VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, nat, iis

I have a windows server 12 dedicated server and I use it mainly for hosting my websites, but I want to set up a vpn on it so that I can browse internet through it (my college restricts a lot of websites).

If I do not enable nat, i can connect to dedicated server through vpn from my college pc but once there dns does not resolve anymore and I can't browse.

If I enable NAT my websites become unreachable from outside.

I found this post

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878046.aspx

about how you can enable webserver behind NAT. But I failed to do it because

- Web server private IP? I'm confused it's the same machine.

Can anyone suggest a way I can achieve what I'm trying to do here, it's been 10 hours I've been reading things and trying stuff with no luck.

Comment: I am confused. Between which two networks does the NAT translate?

Comment: Do you have your server set as your DMZ? It's not directly related to the problem at hand, but just to check if you are following proper network practices.

Answer (score -1):

my best advice is not to try bypassing the campuses firewalls. in doing so  you will be making a back door  that leaves the entire campus network open for assault. if you manage to create this  bypass and something happens  it will be easily traced back to your pc and you and it may result in not only being expelled but having charges brought against you depending on the damage the network suffered. be smart  get a laptop and a wireless hot spot from Verizon or other carrier and use that for non academic activities.